# Replace [contact-form] with PHP include

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a contact form replacement script. Users are able to put `[contact-form]` in their text editor and a contact form will appear. The script below works fine...

```
function ubbreplace($text){
    if (strpos($text, "[contact-form]") !== false) {
       ob_start();
       include("contactform.php");
       $replace = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();
       $text = str_replace("[contact-form]", $replace, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

... but not for my project. Some did not know how to [fix the issue with my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263723/undefined-variable-which-is-actually-defined), so **I'm trying to find a replacement for this**. Other code with the same effect.

What can I do to safely and user friendly replace `[contact-form]` with `include("contactform.php")`?

Comment: What is the probleme with your code ?

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI Nothing really, but I want to find a replacement and I'm not sure what to use to replace `[contact-form]` with a PHP include.

Comment: ob_get_contents is working right ?, why do you wan't something else ?

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI It's working but the code isn't suitable for my project. In  `contactform.php` is database connection code. And with the code in my post, it doesn't connect. I've tried to solve that issue but nobody could get it working, so I'm looking for a replacement